# Compare 2 fields and list the results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this might have been answered or might be too easy, but I haven't found something that's working for me, so here I am.

What I want to do is have a list of people who has 2 types of records which are matching, this is what I have:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| user_id | username | total_exp | exp_since_death |
| 1       | test     | 123       | 123             |
| 2       | abd      | 112       |  43             |
| 3       | bcd      | 144       | 144             |
| 4       | def      |  90       | 50              |
| 5       | asdf     | 173       | 173             |
| 6       | zxvf     | 220       | 113             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

This is what I want to show:

- 1 - test - 123
- 3 - bcd - 144
- 5 - asdf - 173

How can I achieve this? both columns, total_exp and exp_since_death, must have the same value. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select user_id, username, total_exp
from yourtable
where total_exp = exp_since_death;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know it was that simple :P

Answer (score 1):

```
Select user_id, username, total_exp from table
where total_exp = exp_since_death
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select * from table1 where total_exp = exp_since_death
```

Comment: select * would give 1 - test - 123 - 123

Comment: Yes, true ... just selecting all the fields instead 3 specific cols.